# Executing a java application (.jar) in Django

Tags: java, python, django, jar, django-views

While trying to run the following code from django application's views

Code: views.py

```
def tika(fileName):
    os.popen('java -jar tika-app.jar -t %s > textOutput.txt' % fileName)
    return 0

....
# filepath == path to a file
# call java applications
tika(filepath)
....
```

I get the following error messages:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile tika-app.jar

I feel that it has something to do with **file permissions for django application**, but this is just my guess.

If it might help to know - the java application is in the same directory as the django app.

Comment: Maybe you should show the code you're using to execute the jar.

Comment: added code for clarity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the part that was causing the problem:

The java application should be in the Django's project directory level and not at the Django's application directory level.

*Lesson from this*: Even though the running code (views.py) is in the Django's application level, it is run from one level up - the project level.